# Save PDF which is displayed by UIWebView locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I have a `UIViewController` with an `UIWebView` which displays a pdf file depending which row was clicked before in an `UITableView`. Now I want to add a button for the user to save this pdf file locally for offline use. 
Then there is a second `UITableView` which should display the name of the saved pdf and by clicking on it another `UIViewController` appears and displays the  saved pdf on a `UIWebView` offline.
What would be a good way to start?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this way:
1) Add a button to the `View` containing `UIWebView`
2) At button press save the file shown in `UIWebView`
(note: in iOS 5 you must save data that can be easily recreated or downloaded to the  caches directory)

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    BOOL isDir = NO;
    NSError *error;
    //You must check if this directory exist every time
    if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir   == NO)
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    }
    NSString *filePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"someName.pdf"]
    //webView.request.URL contains current URL of UIWebView, don't forget to set outlet for it
    NSData *pdfFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webView.request.URL];
    [pdfFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

3) On application start you need to check what files are stored (iOS can delete cache directory if there is not enough space on iPhone)

Comment: Thanks. Where do I find my saved data now?

Comment: In "Cache" folder (see cachePath variable in code). When you will want to display all saved pdf's first check cache folder that check what files exist into this folder.

Comment: Ok.I said it the wrong way. You created a directory named cachePath. How can I see the content stored in this folder?Sorry I am a beginner and and the moment focusing and learning how to save data in an app.

Comment: Hi. I got it. Took me some time. Actually there is another problem. If I display the content of the cache folder in a tableview I also display all other folders and stuff. Is there a way that I only display my saved data and not things like .DS_Store or com.lmb.TestApp?

Comment: You can use `NSString` [pathExtension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/pathExtension) method. if ([[myString pathExtension] isEqualToString:@".pdf"]) {//your saved pdf's}

Comment: Ok. But at the moment they don't have the ending .pdf because I replaced @"someName.pdf" with self.title. So the name of the saved filed is depending of the title of the view. Maybe I can create a subfolder in caches and write the files into the created subfolder like .../caches/myPDF. How can I create a subfolder in caches? And how to write or read to it. At the moment all stuff is in caches.

Comment: To save into folder use `NSString *filePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdffolder/someName.pdf"]`. Also you can append `.pdf` extension to while when you save it.

Comment: How can I append .pdf to self.title? And how do I check if the folder mypdffolder exists? Because if it doesn't exist I have to create it. In the code you are checking if caches exists and if not it is created. But how I do this with a subfolder in caches?

Comment: `self.title` is just a string. You can append what you want to this string. `NSString *filename = [self.title stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"];`

Comment: This solution is downloading again the PDF as you do `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webView.request.URL];`. How could you access to the already cached PDF being displayed by the WebView?