# How can I save a PDF displayed in a UIWebview control (WITHOUT reloading it from the net)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, uiwebview

I have an app opening URLs that may be PDFs.
I can detect a PDF is opened in the UIWebView control, and if so, I propose to save it locally, in the iPad.
To date, the only solution I found (as described in this topic : [Save PDF which is displayed by UIWebView locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569812/save-pdf-which-is-displayed-by-uiwebview-locally), is to RELOAD the remote PDF file in a new NSData object, then save it to disk.

Is it possible to use the UIWebView's NSData property, and write it directly on the disk, to avoid reloading a potentially large PDF file that is already loaded and displayed ? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't access the data that the UIWebView caches. But, you can download first the PDF and later display in UIWebView from the local PDF.

***EDIT***

Reading your question I understand that:

- First you display the PDF in you UIWebView.
- You ask the user for download.
- You download the PDF (Second request for the PDF).

I propose you:

- Check that the URL is a PDF.
- Ask user to download.
- Download it.
- Display the PDF in UIWebView loading the **local** file.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am already doing. I hope you are wrong saying that I can't access the data of the UIWebView cache...

Comment: @philippe You cannot extract the data from the UIWebView.

Comment: I had already tried this solution using a NSURLConnection object ; that worked, but the user experience was not the same : there was a long delay between the click and the page display, leaving the impression that nothing was happening.

I will uncomment my code, and try to make it less user "unfriendly", and hope somebody will find the direct answer to the question. Thanks anyway for your answer. I will UP it if possible.

Comment: @philippe a UIView with a UIActivityIndicatorView and UIProgressView when you start to download the PDF may result pretty :)

Comment: Well, I do not have enough "reputation" to UP this answer, but it is a correct one. Thanks Jonathan. 

I have used a NSURLConnection object, and a NSMutableData object that are initiated when I receive the "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" message from the UIWebView. 

Then, I had to listen for the NSURLConnection message, including of course the "connectionDidFinishLoading", and saved the NSMutableData object to file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you examine the UIWebView content, using...

```
NSString HtmlCOntent = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.outerHTML"]];
```

It could help you to understand how the WebView deals with the content of the PDF file

Comment: That is not the point. I do not need to know IF there is a PDF in my UIWebView. I need to extract the PDF data (bytes) from the UIWebView.