# Downloading pdf is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiwebview, download

I am trying to download locally the PDF that is there on my UIWebView using code mentioned below.

**[Save PDF which is displayed by UIWebView locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569812/save-pdf-which-is-displayed-by-uiwebview-locally)**

When I type, `NSLog(@"pdfille==%@", pdfFile);`, I see output as `pdfille==(null)`.

Any idea why file is not getting saved?

Is it because I am running the iOS program on Simulator and not on iPad?

Comment: You are storing it in cache That's may be a reason try to save file in document directory and then check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webview 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *myURL = request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"here I get proper URL %@", myURL);    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *filePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"someName.pdf"]
```

PDF will be there in this path Log the path and use Finder>Go >Go to folder